# куда всунуть функцию repaint() чтоб перерисовался график? Java

Tags: java

Разбираюсь с рисованием в Java - в окне нарисована линия и кнопка, когда нажимаю на кнопку, изменяются аргумены и линия должна двигаться. Но она двигается только если окно "пошевелить" (изменить размер мышкой), иначе не перерисовывается.

Много читал , там советуют разные функции и в примере нашел `repaint()`. Но пример очень запутаный и непонятно как это работает. Как можно перерисовать окно нажатием кнопки, куда сунуть `repaint()`, в функцию обработчика, в функцию `main`, или куда то в главный клас? куда не совал, не работает....весь код без обработчику такой:

```
class GraphicsG extends Frame
{                
        static int xy= 200;
        static int xy_= 400;    

        public static void change(){
            xy=xy+50;   
            xy_=xy_+50; 
        }

        public static int write(){    
            return xy;  
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            g.drawLine(xy,xy,xy_,xy_);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            react r = new react();
            FlowLayout fl = new FlowLayout();
            Button b = new Button("OK");
            b.addActionListener(r);
            Panel p = new Panel();
            Frame f = new GraphicsG();
            p.add(b);
            f.add(p);
            f.setLayout(fl);
            f.setSize(400, 150);
            f.setVisible(true);
            f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent ev){
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: О боже. Да это же awt =_=. Повесить какой нибудь Timer или addActionLisencer. И в нем вызывать repaint или еще что. Ну в вашем случае куда нибудь в класс React. Еще можно каждый раз при нажатии кнопки пересоздавать Panel.

Comment: ну по идее надо в `react.actionPerformed` сделать `frame.repaint()`, где `frame` - ваше окно (`f`).